# How to send sms in PDU format from Hyperterminal?

Tags: c#

Hi I want to send Message in PDU format so please can you provide me some suggestion for this?

Comment: what did you try? what is PDU and do you want to send SMS (Short Text Message) to a mobile phone? Help us to help you ;-)

Comment: Sure.I want to send sms to mobile phone which does not support extra languages like Kannada,Tamil,Telugu,Gujarati...etc any Indian Languages so I have done some R&D and I came to know that you can sent SMS using PDU format?Please let me know if you want some more clarification.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/SMS.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/PDUDecoder.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/209636/use-pdu-format-for-send-persian-sms-by-gsm-modem?display=Print

http://www.activexperts.com/download?p1=ax004

command:

at+cmgf=0

at+cmgs=28(length of pdu msg string)

>12458976646485(pdu string)

it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Please see: [use pdu format for send Persian sms by gsm modem](http://www.codeproject.com/Answers/209656/use-pdu-format-for-send-persian-sms-by-gsm-modem)
When Decode In PDU, send number must start without 0 at beginning.